# How to validate the reference IDs in requests in ABP eShopOnAbp app

Tags: abp

In eShopOnAbp, the ordering service doesn't have product data, when a creating order request is started, ordering service gets the product Id  from the request payload (https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp/blob/08070af2bf1429259a9e6755c349bf49edc8d843/services/ordering/src/EShopOnAbp.OrderingService.Domain/Orders/OrderManager.cs#L55).

The question is: does ordering service need to validate the product Id in the creating order request to see if they exist in the product service? The risk of not validating product Id is that the requester can forge a request with invalid product Id to create the order.

The same question applies to the unit price and discount as those data also comes from the request and may not be trusted.

If the validation is necessary, what's the best way to do it? Call product service API from the ordering service?

Comment: Inject `IRepository<Product, Guid> productRepository` and call `_productRepository.GetAsync(orderItem.productId)`.

Comment: @aaron, thanks for your reply, but I don't think injecting the product repository is valid in this case as ordering service uses its own database other than the product service, plus the product knowledge is out of the service boundary of the ordering service.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the main contributors and maintainers of the [eShopOnAbp](https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp) and thank you for your interest.

Yes, in real-life scenario, `productId` should be validated to create an order. But what is **validation** by business-wide?

- Is productId a random guid or corresponds to a real product entity?
- Is the product restricted by a reserve functionality other than stock that needs to be validated from an other microservice?
- Is there any other automated or manual process as business rule for the product before the order process?

You see, this is mainly a business-related issue. After we think about some details, we came across varies of options about these kind of *issues* and we are not domain experts on eshopping.

Since this is a demonstration application, we didn't want to think a lot on the business side. We referenced mainly [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) and [eShopOnDapr](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnDapr).

About the specific case you have shared in OrderManager, I agree that productId should be validated as an entity as a DDD principle.

You have quite valid points and we can improve it for a better real-life scenario based on the community requests.

You can always create issues at https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues with *eShopOnAbp* tag to share your options for technical and business-wide implementations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think in a real-life application, the validations needs to be done. 
The reason I post the question is that I am unable to think of a way to properly perform the validations in a distributed microservice scenario (I am new to microservices), there are two ways I came up with: 1) invoke product service's API in the ordering service to validate the product Id, 2) subscribe the product create/change events and store a minimal copy of the product data in the ordering services and validate the product Id by querying its own database, hope you can give me some ideas.